# How to use System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

How to use System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem for asp.net mvc controller.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more concrete?

Answer (score 8):

1.Wrote SelectItemList collection generate code in Controller/Action method.

```
  ViewData["list"] = new List<SelectListItem>
                       {
                         new SelectListItem {Text = "January", Value = "1"},
                         new SelectListItem {Text = "February", Value = "2"},
                         new SelectListItem {Text = "March", Value = "3"}
                       };
```

2.Wrote render code in Views aspx.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
  <% = Html.DropDownList("list") %>

  <input type="submit" value="send" />
<% } %>
```

3.Get posted value code in Controller/Action method with ModelBinder.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string list)
{
  // process code
}
```

How about this code?
Best,regard.